# Why is an arrow coated in a toxin referred to as poisonous and not venomous?

Tags: word-choice

Why is an arrow always called poisonous in different types of media (games, movies, etc.) when by definition that would not be true.

Venom is delivered by a sting, bite, etc. and is injected into the target while poison needs to be absorbed or ingested for it to take effect. See [this](https://www.science.org.au/curious/people-medicine/poison-vs-venom) nice article from the Australian Academy of Science.

Following that logic, an arrow would be considered venomous as it needs to pierce the target in order to deliver the toxin. It does absolutely nothing if you simply touch it.

Comment: Because an arrow is not an animal…is the main reason, I suppose.

Comment: This probably hangs on the interpretation of "injected". Does an arrow inject the toxin or just carry it in?

Comment: Your article (and definitions) say that a venom is "actively injected via a bite or sting." No arrows. You can inject a poison directly into a person with a needle. That doesn't make it a venom. The definition involves the usual means of production and delivery.

Comment: You need to distinguish specialised biological terminology from terms used in common speech, where language is often less precise. "Poison" is often used generally for any toxic substance. You're looking for language to be utterly consistent and logical, when it isn't. "Poison arrow" is the usual term in English.

Comment: @StuartF but that could be said about proper grammar as well, yet we still try to follow it in speech and writing. But I get your point. It has probably been coined in times when knowledge of biology was rather scarce and it stuck.

Comment: Looks like around the turn of the century ["poison arrow" replaced "envenomed arrow".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poison+arrow%2Cenvenomed+arrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/venomous) explains that

> A ***venomous*** snake, insect, etc., **produces venom** (= a poisonous liquid that can be put into another animal's body by biting or stinging)

An arrow is not a living organism so it does not ***produce*** venom; it is poisonous (poison is *applied* on its tip). Here is how [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/story/whats-the-difference-between-venomous-and-poisonous) differentiates ***venomous*** from ***poisonous***:

> According to biologists, the term ***venomous*** ***is applied to organisms that bite (or sting)*** to inject their toxins, whereas the term ***poisonous applies to organisms that unload toxins when you eat them***. This means that very few snakes are truly poisonous. The vast majority of snake toxins are transferred by bite.

Comment: Merriam-Webster begins its primary definition of [venom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venom) with "a toxic substance produced by some animals..."; If you accept that definition, there's not much more to say, really.

Comment: @phoog I don't think that would be enough to explain it. Poison is also produced by some animals

Comment: There's no reason for ordinary people to talk with precise biological terminology - they often don't (see the argument about what constitutes a "fruit" for instance). Question mentions video games and films, not biological textbooks.

Comment: 'Venomous' is often used metaphorically, but rarely if ever of non–volitional-agents / potential non–volitional-agents. Oxford Languages adds the caveats 'of an animal, especially a snake)  for 'secreting venom, or capable of injecting venom by means of a bite or sting' and 'of a person or their behaviour' for 'full of malice'. Admittedly, the literal use of 'venomous' is extended to jellyfish, fire-corals ... that inject poison if hardly as deliberate actions.

Comment: You could say that the shooter of the arrow is venomous.